# Automatically change the activity of starting another activity

Tags: android, manifest, intentfilter

I have two activities, an activity is a "AppIntro", the other is the "Home page". I want to show the "AppIntro" once, then it becomes not to show it when the application starts go directly to the homepage.

There a way to manipulate the intent-filters from a activity.java.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DefaultIntro"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_default_intro"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a boolean flag in your AppIntroActivity to false.

When you first open this Activity, the flag is false and the activity will load.

When you move from this activity to another then set the flag to true.

On subsequent return to AppIntroActivity, if the flag is true, move immediately to second activity.

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final boolean hasOpenedBefore = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("HASOPEN", false);

if(hasOpenedBefore){
// move immediately to the next Activity
// secondly, remove it from the top activity stack
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to manipulate intent filters defined in manifest file. You can do this

1. When you open the `DefaultIntro` activity save a boolean in `SharedPreference` and set it to `false`
2. Next time onward check this value and if it is `false` directly jump to next activity without setting its layout.

In `DefaultIntro.java` `onCreate`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Boolean showIntro = prefs.getBoolean("showIntro", true);
if(showIntro)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("showIntro", false);
    editor.commit();
}
else
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.java);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```